# What is the effect of sourcing gems from rails-assets.org?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline

So far I’ve been using gems from [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org) in my Gemfiles. While watching an episode at [Drifting Ruby](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/bootstrap-framework-and-ruby-on-rails)  I’ve noticed that the guy is using gems from [rails-assets.org](https://rails-assets.org/). The site description says

> Rails Assets is the frictionless proxy between Bundler and Bower.

I’ve never used Bower and I am not convinced that it is a good idea to start with it now (given that [authors are suggesting to not start new projects with Bower](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/))

What is the effect of e.g. `gem 'rails-assets-jquery', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'` instead of `gem jquery-rails', '~> 4.3'` from rest of the application perspective?

What are intended benefits of using rails-assets.org versions of gems?